# Remap keyboard with scancode map, "Ctrl" + "-" (numpad) to just "-" (numpad)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a kiosk where I have disabled <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. But I want the user to be able to increase and decrease the size of the text in the web browser. (the menues are not visible)

Is there a way to remap this?

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (numpad) to just <kbd>-</kbd> (numpad)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> (numpad) to just <kbd>+</kbd> (numpad)

I have found the extended hexcodes, but it doesn't work for me.

(http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~nsw/enpm808c/scancode.htm)